# Updating the route after renaming the Controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2, rails-routing

I had a contoller named `report` ( so the file name was report_controller.rb )  and a `show` method inside it and route like this:

```
  resources :management, only: [:show] do
    member do
      get 'report' => 'report#show'
    end
  end
```

So I could hit the URL like this below and see my returning JSON and life was good.

```
  http://localhost:3000/management/1/report.json
```

Now I am told I should **pluralize** the name of my controller from report to **reports**.
  So did I.

But now when I go to my previous URL it gives error saying

```
  uninitialized constant ReportController
```

This so annoying. How can I fix this thing now?

Comment: did you rename the file?

Comment: Rename the route, the controller and the name of the file

Comment: Did you do a touch tmp/restart.txt ? (after changing all the instances of the ReportController of course).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both the controller class name and file name need to be plural. Then you'd be about to use the route

```
get 'reports' => reports#show'
```